# ADF Architecture

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

we need to develop a web application using Oracle ADF and jdeveloper 12c. we have 10 modules. Which architecture pattern is best approach in the below 2 patterns.
1. Sum of Parts.
2. Cylinder .
Or is there any other patterns for Production Project.

Answer (score 1):

I work 3 years on ADF framework (11.1.1.7 - 11.1.1.9) and familiar with 12c; There have been a lot of changes that make work easier than before!

I suggest develop modular system and use every module in a base application (present last view to end user), this help you to keep agile development; You can easy test, debug, trace, and update project without trouble! (We hurt this issue, a single big app)

this your choice, every module been an application, or all module been under a unified App, BUT KEEP AWAY TO MERGE ALL OF THEME TO AN APP!!!